# Adding Matrices Method. Double Array. Java

Tags: java, matrix, multidimensional-array

Your have to add matrices. This does not work, and I'm not sure how to fix it! 
The two matrices I have inputed are shown below.

When I output the code, I get the location in the RAM instead of the added matrices.

I'm not sure where it went wrong! I would appreciate HELP! Thank you! :D

```
public static double[][] add(double[][] a1, double [][] a2)
{  
    for (int r = 0; r<a1.length; r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c<a1[r].length; c++)
        {
            a1[r][c] = a1[r][c] + a2[r][c];
        }

    }
    return a1;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    double [][] arr = {{1,3,4},
                               {2,0,1}};

    double [][] arr1 = {{0,0,2},
                                 {5,6,7}};

    System.out.println(Matrix.add(arr, arr1));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling println on an array, and you're seeing the `toString()` returned by an array. Don't do this. Either use `Arrays.deepToString(...)` or else use a for loop to iterate through the array printing out the results.

for example in pseudocode,

```
double[][] result = Matrix.add(...);
for go through rows
  for go through columns
    println the array item in the result array at row, column index
```

Comment: Arrays.toString doesn't work. It gives the location in the RAM for arr and arr1.

Comment: `Arrays.toString` won't work for a double-indexed array. It will return a concatenation of each component's `toString()` result, which won't be any better than what OP is printing now.

Comment: @user2990722: see edit. Also there's the `deepToString(...)` method.

Comment: @TedHopp: you are right, but `Arrays.deepToString(...)` will work.

Answer (score 0):

You're not printing it properly. Try this (**tested and works**):

```
public static double[][] add(double[][] a1, double [][] a2)
{  
    for (int r = 0; r<a1.length; r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c<a1[r].length; c++)
        {
            a1[r][c] = a1[r][c] + a2[r][c];
        }
    }
    return a1;
}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    double [][] arr1 = {{1,3,4},{2,0,1}};
    double [][] arr2 = {{0,0,2},{5,6,7}};
    double[][] sumMatrix = add(arr1,arr2);

    for (double r[] : sumMatrix)
    {
        for (double c : r)
            System.out.print(c + ", ");

        System.out.println("" + '\n');
    }
}
```